# No data displayed on browser, but it is saved on the database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Here is my  php code

```
<?php

include "conn.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$id_guru=htmlentities($_POST['id_guru']);
$id_pelajaran=htmlentities($_POST['id_pelajaran']);
$id_kelas=htmlentities($_POST['id_kelas']);

$query=mysql_query("insert into tbl_jadwal values('','$id_guru','$id_pelajaran','$id_kelas')");

if($query){
    ?><script language="javascript">document.location.href="?page=jadwal_pengajaran&status=1";</script><?php
}else{
    ?><script language="javascript">document.location.href="?page=jadwal_pengajaran&status=2";</script><?php
}


}else{
unset($_POST['submit']);
}


?>

<!--  start page-heading --><title>Sistem Informasi SMP YPPI</title>
<div id="page-heading">
<h1>Jadwal Pengajaran</h1>
</div>
<!-- end page-heading -->

<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="content-table">
<tr>
<th rowspan="3" class="sized"><img src="images/shared/side_shadowleft.jpg" width="20" height="300" alt="" /></th>
<th class="topleft"></th>
<td id="tbl-border-top">&nbsp;</td>
<th class="topright"></th>
<th rowspan="3" class="sized"><img src="images/shared/side_shadowright.jpg" width="20" height="300" alt="" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="tbl-border-left"></td>
<td>
<!--  start content-table-inner ...................................................................... START -->
<div id="content-table-inner">

        <?php
        if($_GET['status']=='1'){
        ?>

        <div id="message-green">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="green-left">Data Tersimpan</td>
            <td class="green-right"><a class="close-green"><img src="images/table/icon_close_green.gif"   alt="" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

        <?php
        }

        if($_GET['status']=='0'){
        ?>

        <div id="message-red">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="red-left">Gagal Menyimpan</td>
            <td class="red-right"><a class="close-red"><img src="images/table/icon_close_red.gif"   alt="" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

        <?php
        }
        ?>

        <form action="?page=jadwal_pengajaran" method="post">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr valign="top">
          <td><!--  start step-holder -->
            <!--  end step-holder -->
              <!-- start id-form -->
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  id="id-form">
                <tr>
                  <th valign="top">Guru</th>
                  <td><select name="id_guru"  class="styledselect_form_1">

                  <?php
                  $guru=mysql_query("select * from data_guru order by nama_guru asc");
                  while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($guru)){
                  ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row1['id_guru'];?>"><?php echo $row1['nama_guru'];?> [ <?php echo $row1['nip'];?> ]                               <option>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>                          

                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <th valign="top">Pelajaran</th>
                  <td><select name="id_pelajaran"  class="styledselect_form_1">

                      <?php
                      $pelajaran=mysql_query("select * from setup_pelajaran order by nama_pelajaran asc");
                      while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($pelajaran)){
                      ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row2['id_pelajaran'];?>"><?php echo $row2['nama_pelajaran'];?></option>
                      <?php
                      }
                      ?>    

                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <th valign="top">Kelas</th>
                  <td><select name="id_kelas"  class="styledselect_form_1">

                      <?php
                      $kelas=mysql_query("select * from setup_kelas order by nama_kelas asc");
                      while($row3=mysql_fetch_array($kelas)){
                      ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row3['id_kelas'];?>"><?php echo $row3['nama_kelas'];?></option>
                      <?php
                      }
                      ?>    

                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <th>&nbsp;</th>
                  <td valign="top"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-submit" />
                      <input type="reset" class="form-reset"  />
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            <!-- end id-form  -->
          </td>
          <td><!--  start related-activities -->
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="images/shared/blank.gif" width="695" height="1" alt="blank" /></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

        <p><em>*Tidak boleh 1 Kelas, 1 Pelajaran di ajarkan oleh 2 Guru atau lebih<br /></em> </p>           
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <!--  start product-table ..................................................................................... -->
    <form id="mainform" action="">
    <table border="0" width="71%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table">
    <tr>
        <th width="13%" class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">Nomor</a>   </th>
        <th width="24%" class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">Nama Guru</a></th>
        <th width="26%" class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">NIP</a></th>
        <th width="24%" class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">Mata Pelajaran</a></th>
        <th width="24%" class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">Kelas</a></th>
        <th width="13%" class="table-header-options line-left"><a href="">Aksi</a></th>
    </tr>


    **<?php
    $view=mysql_query("*SELECT* FROM tbl_jadwal jadwal, setup_kelas kelas, setup_pelajaran pelajaran, data_guru guru where          jadwal.id_kelas=kelas.id_kelas and jadwal.id_pelajaran=pelajaran.id_pelajaran and jadwal.id_guru=guru.id_guru order by id_jadwal         asc");

    $no=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($view)){
    ?>  
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no=$no+1;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['nama_guru'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['nip'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['nama_pelajaran'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['nama_kelas'];?></td>
        <td class="options-width">
        <a href="" title="Delete" class="icon-2 info-tooltip"></a>
        <a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-5 info-tooltip"></a>            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <!--  end product-table................................... --> 
    </form>



<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<!--  end content-table-inner ............................................END  -->
</td>
<td id="tbl-border-right"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="sized bottomleft"></th>
<td id="tbl-border-bottom">&nbsp;</td>
<th class="sized bottomright"></th>
</tr>
</table>**
```

When i test the code on browser, there's nothing displayed, only empty table, but there is saved data on the database.
I believe the problem came from

```
 **<?php
$view=mysql_query("*SELECT* FROM tbl_jadwal jadwal, setup_kelas kelas, setup_pelajaran pelajaran, data_guru guru where             jadwal.id_kelas=kelas.id_kelas and jadwal.id_pelajaran=pelajaran.id_pelajaran and jadwal.id_guru=guru.id_guru order by id_jadwal         asc");

$no=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($view)){
?>  
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $no=$no+1;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nama_guru'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nip'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nama_pelajaran'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nama_kelas'];?></td>
    <td class="options-width">
    <a href="" title="Delete" class="icon-2 info-tooltip"></a>
    <a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-5 info-tooltip"></a>            
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

But still I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: **Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: FYI - `<script language="JavaScript">` There is no attribute "language" it has been `deprecated`.

Answer (score 0):

is that

```
 $view=mysql_query("*SELECT* FROM ...
```

from the paste, it should look like this:

```
 $view=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ...
```

and

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($view)){
```

will give you a numbered array, not an associative array. Thus you need to **EITHER** access fields in their order:

```
 <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td> ...
```

**or** use assoc (**NOT BOTH**):

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($view)){
```

Comment: Actually, `The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.`

Comment: @Damien Pirsy: you are right, upvote, didn't ever see that (I'm not using this quite often...)

Comment: did you correct your `SELECT` statement as mentioned in the above answers?

Comment: do a `var_dump($row)` right within the `while` loop, I assume your field names aren't properly spelled or wrong?

Comment: My field names id jadwal, id_kelas , id_pelajaran , id_guru .

Comment: Then it should be `<td><?php echo $row['id_guru'];?></td>` and not `<td><?php echo $row['nama_guru'];?></td> `

Comment: I posted this fields problems on my last question, sir. Would you kindly do a quick check?